# Get Xively datastream in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, xively

I am trying to get the datastream from Xively using [Xively4J](https://github.com/xively/Xively4J). I have download [snapshot jar from Sonatype repo](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~xively). I figured that there is a `getDatastreams()` method, but this method is strange because it doesn't take arguments. How can I use this method to get the datastream that I want from a specific Xively feed? Can someone give me an example to use this method?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet which lists the channels' names of your specific feed:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.xively.client.XivelyService;
import com.xively.client.model.Datastream;
import com.xively.client.model.Feed;


public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Feed feed = XivelyService.instance().feed().get(6630948);  //your feedID as argument

        System.out.println("channels of feed "+feed.getId()+ ":");

        Collection<Datastream> datastreams = feed.getDatastreams();
        Iterator<Datastream> datastreamsIterator=datastreams.iterator();

        while(datastreamsIterator.hasNext()){           
            Datastream currentDatastream=datastreamsIterator.next();    
            System.out.println(currentDatastream.getId());
        }


    }//end main

}//end class
```

Make sure you have added your API key on the file src/main/res/config.properties
 of the library without any quotes. e.g.:

```
# The key used for authenticating API calls.
api.key=rtBB60ref6TRi23yQeWMfI0034DRDsYdd4lbJjRZoFLQI00
```

Comment: bhantol are you sure you know what xively and xively4j is?
2 of the edits you propose make the post incorrect.
1)the correct path is the one before the edit(main/res/config.properties)
2)every feed has many channels so your correction was not only unnecessary but made the sentence imply that thre is one channel with many names which is nonsense...